# How to calculate impulse if applied force is not constant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

For example, I have a stationary object with an applied force that is increasing over time to a maximum of $500\, \rm N$.  If this applied force rises to $500\, \rm N$ over $100\, \rm ms$, the object does not move but if this force rises to $500\, \rm N$ over $2\, \rm ms$, the object moves.
How would I calculate the impulses if the change of the applied force is not constant?

Comment: Please explain? What makes it move in one scenario and not in the other. What is opposing the force? Where does an _impulse_ come into play here? Also note, that impulses happen over infinitesimally small time slices $\Delta t \ll 2\text{ ms}$

Answer (score 2):

If your force is not constant then you would need calculus to determine the impulse directly from the (net) force.

Since the net force is equal to the rate of change of momentum $F=\text dp/\text dt$, we can integrate the force over time to determine the change in momentum

$$\Delta p=\int F\,\text dt$$

Many algebra-based physics classes bypass this issue by only focusing on the *average* force though

$$F_\text{avg}=\frac1{\Delta t}\int F\,\text dt=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that your object does not move when applied force rises to 500N in 100ms, that means your object is being resisted from motion by something else. It might be clamped, it might be friction. You have to account for the momentum loss due to such interactions. Or else you may not compute anything sensible.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the impulse imparted as the integral of the force applied on the over time. First you need to find the relation of the force and time. Then using that relation express force in terms of time. Then you can integrate it over time. In the mentioned case the force varies with time linearly. So you could express the 2ms case as F = (500/2ms)*t. Then integration will give you the answer.
If the object is resisted by something like friction then in both of those cases you had mentioned, the object will move or not move, if the friction is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude of impulse equals the area under the force curve

$$ J = \int F(t)\,{\rm d} t $$

and in your case if the force curve is $F(t) = F_{\rm max} \frac{t}{\Delta t}$ then

$$ J = \int_0^{\Delta t} F_{\rm max} \frac{t}{\Delta t}\,{\rm d} t = \tfrac{1}{2} \Delta t \;F_{\rm max} $$

which is exactly the area of triangle with height $F_{\rm max}$ and base $\Delta t$.